# Dropping wire from attic through existing interior drywall wall

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I need to put an outlet in an existing interior wall. I can get to the top plate of the wall from the attic, and I can connect to the supply for the other outlets in the room from there too.

My question is if it's ok to just drop the wire through the empty space and into the new outlet box. I.e. the wire would just be dangling, and not fastened to the stud.

Can I use regular romex, or do I need armored wire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this cable is going through a concealed space between access points and adding support is impracticable, NEC 334.30(B) applies:

> **(B) Unsupported Cables.** Nonmetallic-sheathed cable shall
>   be permitted to be unsupported where the cable:
>
> (1) Is fished between access points through concealed
>   spaces in finished buildings or structures and supporting is impracticable.
>
> (2) Is not more than 1.4 m (4½ ft) from the last point of
>   cable support to the point of connection to a luminaire
>   or other piece of electrical equipment and the cable and
>   point of connection are within an accessible ceiling.

So, go ahead and use NM if you wish.  (The NEC has equivalent wording in 330.30(D) for MC cable and 320.30(D) for AC cable, BTW.)