# Does a conduit running through a ceiling need to be supported?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit, nec

I will be running wire through a basement ceiling (not a drop ceiling) and I would like to avoid cutting holes in the drywall. I know that the wire on its own would need to be supported and secured to the joists. However, if the wire is running through a conduit, does the conduit need supporting or can it rest on the ceiling?

Comment: In short, you don't need the conduit, and adding conduit probably makes support required.

Answer (score 0):

A wire is generally not acceptable, period (exception might be a grounding wire as a lone wire.)

A cable (several wires in one outer jacket, such as NM/B aka "Romex® - a brand name) is NOT required to be attached where it cannot be accessed **if** it's a retrofit into an existing space, (apparently the case here) generally.

Conduit is required for protection of wires and IS required to be attached. There MIGHT be a pass for flexible conduit to be treated like cable for a retrofit, I'm not sure. There is for AC & MC cables, but not finding anything for flex conduit, even though it's very similar to AC & MC cables.

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/108789/18078 and https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/140413/18078 and https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/215342/18078